# Why close dropdown, wherever I click on opened modal?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, dropdown

I would like to ask some help. Here is that page: [link](http://authenticwristwatches.co.uk/ice-watch-sy-ph-m-s-14-ice-sweety-peach-mini-silicone-ladies-watches)
If I click on second retailer's voucher button, the page show some code. When I click to "get voucher code" everything is working nice. The code will be showing and a modal visible.

But when I click anywhere on modal (.sweet-overlay, .sweet-alert or button),
The dropdown is close. :(

I tried everything, but still not working for me. For example:

```
$('.sweet-overlay').on({
    "click":function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

I thing that is the simpliest solution, but why not working?

Thank you in advance the possible solutions.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem. I went to the link, then I clicked on "Voucher codes" of the second retailer. Then I clicked on "Get voucher code" and it opened a new tab  with the correct shop. Also, in your page it shows me a modal saying that the voucher code is activated. I don't see any problem here. What is the exact problem?

Comment: After all, when You click anywhere on modal or outside the modal, the dropdown is closing. :( I want the user to see the displayed codes instantly.

Comment: show me your code control the `open` class?

Comment: Do you want to see the php source?

Answer (score 1):

1st I found a problem in your site, the id should be unique and I see it multiple time, do you have control over this?

`<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown keep-open">`

Try `preventDefault`

Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('.sweet-overlay').on({
    "click":function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried an other solution and it stayed here.


$('.dropdown.keep-open').on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { $(this).attr('closable', false); },
    "click":             function() { },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return $(this).attr('closable') == 'true'; }
});

$('.keep-open #dLabel').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('closable', true );
 }
})
 With this js the dropdown stay open, but, when I click other dropdown, the last is not closing.

Comment: @user8106622 that solved your problem? then just post as answer and accept it.

Comment: This working, but, If I use this, the dropdown not closing, if open an other.

Comment: @user8106622 try to reproduce your problem here so we can debug, it is hard to debug just from what it looks like

Comment: Okay, now I'm added the other solution, which would be right for me.

$('.dropdown.keep-open').on({ "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { $(this).attr('closable', false); }, "click": function() { }, "hide.bs.dropdown": function() { return $(this).attr('closable') == 'true'; } }); $('.keep-open #dLabel').on({ "click": function() { $(this).parent().attr('closable', true ); } })

With this js now the dropdown not closing, when I click anywhere on modal, but if I click on one more dropdown, the last one is stay open or toggle.

Comment: Just try to open all dropdown. It's not good that the previous stay open.

Comment: @Donald creat a simple code snipet so people can play around, now we can't really do anything to debug, for example a snipet like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/o5x3jrgk/

Comment: I couldn't do it, because it contains shortcode also and very difficult to do without the associated plugins for me. I must accept it as it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to not use `data-dismiss="modal"`

you actually can prevent the closing of your modal by using the combination of 
preventDefault() ,stopPropagation()

```
    $('.sweet-overlay').on({
        "click":function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm can not find anywhere: data-dismiss="modal"